# Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION"

Tags: cmake

I faced with an issue that my installed on Ubuntu `cmake`

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.17.2
```

doesn't recognize `CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION` command.

So, my `CMakeLists.txt` with dependent option example from [cmake.org/v3.16](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/CMakeDependentOption.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project(myexe)

CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION(USE_FOO "Use Foo" ON
                       "USE_BAR;NOT USE_ZOT" OFF)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
```

The following error is displayed when running `cmake`:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION):
  Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION".
```

Why does it happen because the spec says it is supported? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add

```
include(CMakeDependentOption)
```

before accessing this function.